# Get MySQL row with HTML textbox, return column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MySQL database containing a table called hashes_md5 with these columns: `plain,hash`. I want to make a simple PHP script where the user inputs a text within a textbox. The php script should look for this text in the column 'plain' and if it exists, return the value from the column 'hash' from the corresponding row.
I currently only have the connection to the MySQL server done:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost",
"root","password");
or die ("Error occured. Are the credentials correct?");

mysql_select_db("hashes")
or die ("Error occured. The database doesn't exist.");

$query = "SELECT plain, hash FROM hashes_md5";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
   {
   echo "$row->plain, $row->hash <br>";

   }
?>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have any code or are you looking for a tutorial on interacting with a DB?

Comment: I currently only have the connection to the MySQL database done in PHP (editing it above, forgot it). I also know the needed SQL commands; however I don't know how to give the value of the HTML textbox to the PHP script.

Comment: It will be addressable by the name attribute of the element in your form. Depending on your forms method it will be `$_POST` or `$_GET`. For a functional example please include your HTML form.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows()` - `LIKE` - `WHERE`.... `COUNT()` too many ways to do this.

Comment: The browser gets information to the sever through HTTP. There's generally two methods to perform an HTTP connection: GET and POST. And there's a few ways to GET and POST data, including links, forms and XHR (AKA ajax). Links and forms cause page loads, and XHR happens without reloading the page. Which do you prefer?

Comment: You also need to post your HTML form. Guesswork is fun when playing charades, just not for coding questions.

Answer (score 0):

And what have you done?
here is the SQL command rest is up to you:

```
 SELECT hash FROM hashes_md5 WHERE plain='$plain_escaped_hash'
```

but are you sure? hash is a one way encoding, you can easily MD5() the input and print it out! so if user wants to crack the hash he can enter the hash and you can search for him in the database for the equal plain text of his hash !

Comment: I do know the needed commands in SQL, but I couldn't find any doc etc. how to give the value of a html textbox to the php script.